# Firebase user property boolean value. (true or false)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I want to have some way to see how many percent of my app's users have purchased the "premium upgrade".

The premium upgrade can be purchased one time, through an in app purchase. The `boolean` value is stored on the device by Google Play. I would like to see that 'value' in Firebase.

I thought about setting a user property with the name **Premium**, but can't find out how I can set the value to `true` or `false`.

Is this the correct way, or is there a better method for just a `boolean` value?

Comment: Where do you need to store the property "Premium" in the smartphone of each user or in a central database?

Comment: @DavidCorral The property "Premium" is stored on the device by Google Play. I just want a way to see how many percent of users have the premium upgrade. (In Firebase?)

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible. I would come up with another solution, like: use Firebase Database to store the par {"uid" : "premium"}, where uid is the token that every device has and premium a value like 1/0 or yes/no in order to note if that user is premium or not. 

Firebase database is very simple to use :-) Here you can find more info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Comment: @DavidCorral How can I view that data in Firebase?

Comment: Access to your Firebase Console (https://console.firebase.google.com/), then select the project which you are using and finally, in the left menu, click on "Database". There you can see the whole database of your project. Note that is a NoSQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Your post indicates the premium upgrade is an in-app purchase.  In that case, consider using [Firebase Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/).  An [event is generated](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485) for in-app purchases:

> When a user completes an in-app purchase that is processed by the App
>   Store on iTunes or Google Play. The product ID, product name,
>   currency, and quantity are passed as parameters.

The statistics about the purchase are summarized on the [Analytics Dashboard](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317517?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489#in-app-purchases):

> Users: number and percentage of users who completed in-app
>   transactions

I haven't used Analytics for this purpose, but it seems like it might satisfy your needs.

Comment: Thanks. I can already see this data in Firebase. However, I asked for a true/false because I have more stuff I want to see. The premium upgrade was an example for the variable.

Comment: It's not clear from your question if you are asking about use of Firebase Database to store the boolean value.  One drawback of using the database is that for greatest safety, you would want to set the [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) on your database to allow writes only from authenticated users.  That would require your users to sign in, which is probably undesirable in terms of user experience.

Comment: I even put it in the title.. A login won't be an option for just analytics.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab: Your post doesn't contain the word Analytics.  That omission, plus the comments misled me. I see the firebase-analytics tag now.

Comment: 'User Properties' are part of 'Analytics'.